# jq: setpaths with regex on paths, how to handle paths that end with an integer which produce an error?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following object:

```
{
  "domainId": "hidden",
  "lastUsed": "Thu Oct 04 2018",
  "lastUsedTimestamp": 1538673002460,
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1538673002460
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536087726701
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536086675399
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536182646984
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert all `lastUsedTimestamp` values to a date. This works with:

```
reduce (paths | select(.[-1] == "lastUsedTimestamp")) as $p 
  (.;setpath($p; getpath($p) / 1000 | todate))
```

But what if I had other timestamp keys such as `createdTimestamp` or `startTimestamp` in other places of the object? For instance:

```
{
  "domainId": "hidden",
  "lastUsed": "Thu Oct 04 2018",
  "lastUsedTimestamp": 1538673002460,
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1538673002460
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536087726701
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536086675399,
      "createdTimestamp": 1536086675399
    },
    {
      "userId": "hidden",
      "lastUsedTimestamp": 1536182646984,
      "startTimestamp": 1536182646984
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried

```
reduce (paths | select(.[-1] | endswith("Timestamp")) as $p 
  (.;setpath($p; getpath($p) / 1000 | todate))
```

or an equivalent with `test` but paths that end with an integer make it fail.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem, `walk/1` is often convenient:

```
def timestamps:
  with_entries(if .key | endswith("Timestamp")
               then .value |= (./1000 | todate) else . end);

walk( if type == "object" then timestamps else . end )
```

### As a one-liner

If you want a one-liner:

```
walk( if type == "object" then with_entries(if .key | endswith("Timestamp") then .value |= (./1000 | todate) else . end) else . end)
```

If your jq allows the `else .` to be omitted, this becomes a bit more digestible:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(if .key | endswith("Timestamp") then .value |= (./1000 | todate) end) end)
```

Comment: Thanks, your answers are like clockwork. I'll accept this answer as it is more to the point.

Comment: by the way, how do you get a jq that allows `else .` to be omitted?

Comment: Either make from master, or obtain a recent Windows version as per the guidelines at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

Answer (score 2):

To supress errors use `... ?` operator, which is a shorthand for `try ...`. For example:

```
reduce (paths|select(.[-1]|endswith("Timestamp")?)) as $p
(.; setpath($p; getpath($p)/1000|todate))
```

Comment: thanks, this indeed works, but it seems a little bit ugly to me. Since posting I've actually also thought of using `paths(numbers)` which works in my case as timestamps will always by numbers. I'll wait a little bit to see if there is a "better" answer and if not, will accept yours.